# clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation) XCode and wxWidgets

Tags: c++, xcode, macos, wxwidgets

I'm trying to start a project in XCode 8 using wxWidgets 3.1.0 on OS X 10.11
After downloading wxWidgets-3.1.0 I've built and make everything according to the /docs/osx/install.txt

Now I tried to create a new project and followed their guide: https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Creating_Xcode_projects_for_wxWidgets_applications

- I followed almost every step exactly as instructed. (Static and Debug)
- I didn't find the Summary Tab and a Choose Info.plist File Button, I chose it over General under Identity (which may be the same)

Then I tried to compile and run.
I'm getting Warnings and 1 Error.

Warning: Telling me to check dependencies

```
wxcocoa.xcconfig line 3: Unable to find included file "wx.xcconfig"
Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file '/Users/me/Desktop/git/xcode/wx_mac_xcode/Info_cocoa.plist'.
```

Error:

```
Ld /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wx_mac_xcode-bhbnjqgpmqtgwxhfxmjhvrtjnraz/Build/Products/Debug/Static.app/Contents/MacOS/Static normal x86_64
    cd /Users/me/Desktop/git/xcode/wx_mac_xcode
    export MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=10.5
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++ -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.11.sdk -L/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wx_mac_xcode-bhbnjqgpmqtgwxhfxmjhvrtjnraz/Build/Products/Debug -F/Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wx_mac_xcode-bhbnjqgpmqtgwxhfxmjhvrtjnraz/Build/Products/Debug -filelist /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wx_mac_xcode-bhbnjqgpmqtgwxhfxmjhvrtjnraz/Build/Intermediates/wx_mac_xcode.build/Debug/Static.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Static.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/../Frameworks -mmacosx-version-min=10.5 -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -framework WebKit -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenGL -framework QTKit -framework WebKit -framework IOKit -framework Carbon -framework Cocoa -framework AudioToolbox -framework OpenGL -framework QTKit -lz -stdlib=libstdc++ -lwx_osx_cocoa_static -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wx_mac_xcode-bhbnjqgpmqtgwxhfxmjhvrtjnraz/Build/Intermediates/wx_mac_xcode.build/Debug/Static.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Static_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/me/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/wx_mac_xcode-bhbnjqgpmqtgwxhfxmjhvrtjnraz/Build/Products/Debug/Static.app/Contents/MacOS/Static

ld: library not found for -lwx_osx_cocoa_static 
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Double checked every step, but don't know how to fix those dependencies.
Project and library are debug mode

Cheers

Comment: did you build the library in Terminal? What is the exact configure line you used? (you can find it in the <builddir>/config.log file). Did you move the results of "./wx-config --cxxflags and "./wx-config --libs" as appropriate?

Comment: I followed the install.txt and used ../configure --enable-debug

Comment: the default SDK on OSX is still 10.5 even though it is not supported anymore. Please try "../configure --enable-debug --with-macosx-version-min=10.{7+} --with-cocoa" and try again. Check "../configure --help" for proper name of the option.

Comment: tried, error still persists

Comment: try "../configure --with-cocoa --enable-debug --with-macosx-version-min=10.x --disable-shared". Also don't forget after recompiling to reset compile properties of the project in Xcode.(that are "Header Search Path", "Preprocessor Directives" and "Other Linker Options"). x is the appropriate version of 7+ for you minimal target OSX.

Comment: I redid everything:
1. deleted build-cocoa-debug
2. created build-cocoa-debug and went into the folder
3. used your command line and make to build everything
4. used the guide and followed every instruction to the point and the error is still thrown

Comment: In the guide I'm never accessing the build-cocoa-debug folder. I'm only using /build/osx/wxcococa.xcodeproj and /samples/minima/minimal_cococa.xcodeproj